# Codeigniter active record bug? Query builder added a line

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, activerecord

I think I have a problem with codeigniter (version 3.1.2) active record...

My model function is:

```
function select_country($ID, $typec)
{
    $data = '';

    $this ->db -> select ('*');
    $this ->db -> where ('ID', $ID);
    $query = $this ->db -> get ('country');

    if ($query->num_rows()>0){

        foreach ($query->result() as $row){
            $data=$row->$typec;
        }
    }   

    return $data;

}
```

When I run it I get this error:

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM `country` WHERE `ID` = '6'' at line 1

```
SELECT `ads`, * FROM `country` WHERE `ID` = '6'
```

Filename: models/Country_model.php

Line Number: 40

I noticed an additional line : "SELECT `ads`, * FROM `country` WHERE `ID` = '6'" but I don't know from where is it. There is no 'ads' column.

If I use `"$query = $this ->db -> query ('SELECT * FROM country WHERE ID = '.$ID); "` there is no error.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this....

```
function select_country($ID, $typec)
{
    $data = '';

    $this ->db ->select ('*');
    $this->db->from('country');
    $this ->db ->where ('ID', $ID);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows()>0){
    $row = $query->row();//only on row on result so no need to use `result()`
    $data = $row->$typec 
    }   

    return $data;

}
```

More simpler query:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('country', array('ID' => $ID));
```

Comment: The same error 
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064  
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM `country` WHERE `ID` = '1 '' at line 1

SELECT `ads`, * FROM `country` WHERE `ID` = '1 '

Filename: models/Country_model.php

Line Number: 121

Comment: and if I use the simpler query I get:                                                                                                                                  
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'ads' in 'field list'

SELECT `ads` FROM `country` WHERE `ID` = '1 '

Filename: models/Country_model.php

Line Number: 124

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still looking for an answer but make sure you don't call the select_country()-function after starting a new DB-query.

Basically something like this *MAY* cause this bug:

```
// Start new query using the Query-Builder 
$this->db->select('*')->from('something');

// Get some additional data
$countries = $this->your_model->select_countries($your_id, $some_type);

// Execute the query
$query = $this->db->where_in('country_id', $countries)->get();
```

If you do something like this, try calling your select_countries()-function before starting the new query:

```
// FIRST: Get some additional data
$countries = $this->your_model->select_countries($your_id, $some_type);

// Start new query using the Query-Builder 
$this->db->select('*')->from('something');

// Execute the query
$query = $this->db->where_in('country_id', $countries)->get();
```